# Getting unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration

Tags: grails, groovy

Iam new to groovy on grails.
In my grails application i have to edit a property file without deleting other key values for that Iam using `apache commons` following code

```
PropertiesConfiguration conf = new PropertiesConfiguration("config.properties");
            props.setProperty("key", "value");
            conf.save();
```

In `BuildConfig.groovy` I have included the depentencies

```
dependencies {

        compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:2.2'
        compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'      
    }
```

While executing `grails compile` the dependencies seems to be downloaded without any error, but that Iam getting the compilation error

```
 unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration
  [groovyc]  @ line 5, column 1.
  [groovyc]    import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;
  [groovyc]    ^
  [groovyc]
```

What additional settings that i need to do in grails please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration;
```

Note the 2 at the end of configuration!